# magic_quotes_gpc is on

Tags: php, zend-framework, magic-quotes-gpc

I have a site with I developed with Zend.

I turned off `magic_quotes_gpc` in the application.ini file like this:

```
phpSettings.magic_quotes_gpc = 0
phpSettings.magic_quotes_runtime = 0
phpSettings.magic_quotes_sybase = 0
```

But I can see when user want to update or add data in DB with this application, slash will add before it if there is any quotation mark!!

I contacted to the server administrator, he told me all of this properties are OFF!!

But when I echo `get_magic_quotes_gpc();`, it prints 1.

What should I do?!!

Comment: What PHP version is running?  Just a simple `echo phpversion();` should suffice.  `echo PHP_VERSION;` should give you this info too.  This is important because this exact behavior has changed over the course of PHP versions.

Comment: now this deviates from your question, but are you able to upgrade PHP at all?  5.2 is outdated.

Comment: no, I dont think so!!! :(

Comment: `set_magic_quotes_runtime(false);` at the top of every single script will likely fix your problem temporarily.  Otherwise upgrade.  Upgrading PHP is the definitive solution even if this means finding someone else to admin your server and making sure your own code is up to date.

Comment: I did , but when i run these code `echo get_magic_quotes_runtime();
echo get_magic_quotes_gpc();` for first one result is 0 and second one is 1!!!!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21983/discussion-between-afsane-and-bob-the-destroyer)